# Convert X,Y floating point coordinates to binary matrix and then perform a Hough line transform

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, image-processing, hough-transform

Is it possible to compute a hough line transform of array of xy floating points, similar to this matlab code in python?

> ```
> BW=full(sparse(x,y,true));
> ```

the data looks like

[image]

Comment: I have tried to use ransac on the problem but its not working well enough because of noise clusters in some of the data similar to this [link](http://imgur.com/HNQburv)

Comment: Is your question how to convert X,Y points to a binary matrix in python? Or how to perform a hough transform?

Comment: How to convert  X,Y points to a binary matrix in python, but the points are floating points not integers. I shall make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example in MATLAB only works on integer (x,y) coordinates.

For example

```matlab
% I use a 10x10 identity matrix to simulate a line of points
% And scale the resulting x, y coordinates to be floating point 
[X, Y] = find(eye(10));
X = X * 0.1;
Y = Y * 0.1;
A = full(sparse(X, Y, true));
```

Throws the error

> Error using sparse. Index into matrix must be an integer.

If you want to convert floating point coordinates into a binary matrix, the only way I know of is to decimate your space.

```matlab
% Precision of the decimated grid
scale = .01;

% Scale the X, Y values to be integers greater than 1
row_indices = round((Y - min(Y))/scale) + 1;    
col_indices = round((X - min(X))/scale) + 1;

% row values also need to be flipped 
% i.e. y = 0 should be the maximum row in the matrix to maintain the same orientation of the coordinate system
row_indices = max(row_indices) -  row_indices + 1;

% Create matrix using your method
A = full(sparse(row_indices, col_indices, true));

% Each row and column in A corresponds to the value in these range vectors
xrange = min(X):scale:max(X);
yrange = max(Y):-scale:min(Y);
```

To test whether these transformations produced the desired result. I plotted the matrix.

```
figure; 
subplot(1,2,1); imagesc(A);
xticks(1:20:100); xticklabels(xrange(1:20:end));
yticks(1:20:100); yticklabels(yrange(1:20:end));
subplot(1,2,2); plot(X, Y, 'ko');
```

And it's looking good.

[image: Binary matrix on the left, plotted points on the right]

A similar approach should be easy to implement using numpy.

Comment: Yeah, this is what i was thinking, but the problem is that i have really small differences between points, so the smallest difference is about 0.0000001 and the largest being about 1. So by decimating the array it has the consequence of having a huge array with very few elements, and because of the size of the array, processing it would take a long time, which is not possible in my case. Do you think there are any other methods to solve this?

Comment: If you number of points is small, you could implement your own hough transform as described in [this wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform#Example_1).